# how do I iterate only once per function call

Tags: python

I have a list of things I want to iterate over and return each of them only once per function call.

What I've tried:

```
tl = """
zza,zzb,zzc,zzd,zze,zzf,zzg,zzh,zzi,zzj,zzk,zzl,zzm,zzn,zzo,zzp,zzq,zzr,zzs,zzt,zzu,zzv,zzw,zzx,zzy,zzz
"""

# convert each string into list
result = [x.strip() for x in tl.split(",")]

index = 0

def func():
    return result[index]
    index += 1
```

It's saying code unreachable at the index += 1 part.
The output I want is zza the first time I call func(), then zzb, then zzc, etc.

Appreciate the help.

**EDIT:
I've found this answer to work well and easily readable:**

```
# list of elements seperated by a comma
tl = """
zza,zzb,zzc,zzd,zze,zzf,zzg,zzh,zzi,zzj,zzk,zzl,zzm,zzn,zzo,zzp,zzq,zzr,zzs,zzt,zzu,zzv,zzw,zzx,zzy,zzz
"""
# split each string by comma to get a list
result = [x.strip() for x in tl.split(",")]

# initialize the object
iterator_obj = iter(result)

print(next(iterator_obj))
print(next(iterator_obj))
print(next(iterator_obj))
```

output:

```py
zza
zzb
zzc
```

Comment: what do you mean return only once. Are you trying to find the unique values in this?

Comment: I want to return first the first element on function call, then the second element, then the 3d etc

Comment: It's unreachable because it appears after a `return`.  `return` immediately returns the expression `result[index]`

Comment: Try using into the `yield` keyword.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Next time please be more clear in with your question. Looking at the answers of others, most of them thought you were trying to get the function to return the index of an element. It looks like you were looking for a yield implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ there is an operator that will increment a variable with `++i` incrementing before evaluation and `i++` after evaluation

```
(i:=i+1) #same as ++i (increment, then return new value)
(i:=i+1)-1 #same as i++ (return the incremented value -1)
```

so the function you want is

```
def func():
    global index
    return result[(index := index+1)-1]
```

the `:=` operator is new in python 3.8

so

```
tl = """
zza,zzb,zzc,zzd,zze,zzf,zzg,zzh,zzi,zzj,zzk,zzl,zzm,zzn,zzo,zzp,zzq,zzr,zzs,zzt,zzu,zzv,zzw,zzx,zzy,zzz
"""

# convert each string into list
result = [x.strip() for x in tl.split(",")]

index = 0

def func():
    global index
    return result[(index := index + 1) - 1]

print(func())
print(func())
print(func())
print(func())
```

prints

```
zza
zzb
zzc
zzd
```

Comment: It still says index is unbound for me

Comment: Added the global function so index is not unbound

Answer (score 1):

Because return statement exit the function, any statement after that is not reachable. A quick fix to your code:

```
tl = """
zza,zzb,zzc,zzd,zze,zzf,zzg,zzh,zzi,zzj,zzk,zzl,zzm,zzn,zzo,zzp,zzq,zzr,zzs,zzt,zzu,zzv,zzw,zzx,zzy,zzz
"""

# convert each string into list
result = [x.strip() for x in tl.split(",")]

next_index = 0

def func():
    global next_index
    next_index += 1
    return result[next_index-1]
```

BTW, your func behaves like built-in `next`. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel:

```
# convert each string into iterator
result = (x.strip() for x in tl.split(","))
# next(result) will get to the next item on the list
```

Comment: How else would you solve this problem without using the global keyword?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, how would I go about incrementing index outside of the function?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to be able to only return one item of your string at a time per function call, you need to use an generator:

```py
def func(items):
    string_list = items.split(",")
    for i in range(len(string_list)):
        yield string_list[i]

tl = """
zza,zzb,zzc,zzd,zze,zzf,zzg,zzh,zzi,zzj,zzk,zzl,zzm,zzn,zzo,zzp,zzq,zzr,zzs,zzt,zzu,zzv,zzw,zzx,zzy,zzz
"""

item = func(tl)
```

To pull a value out, in order, use

```
next(item) # zza
next(item) # zzb
...
```

Every time you call `next`, a new value will be returned.

As an aside, anything after return statement will not run, which is why your `index += 1` did not work. Return stops the function from running.